# Можно ли с помощью React JS/React Native писать приложения одновременно для iOS/Android и для веба

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Есть ли техническая возможность создавать с помощью реакта приложение одновременно и для веба и для мобильных платформ? Для мобилок и веба нужен совершенно разный код или пойдет один и тот же с какой-то адаптацией?

Comment: всё возможно! но что вам надо конкретно?

Comment: Надо сделать сайт/приложение под ios, Android и браузерную версию.
Мне надо понять, те разработчики с которыми я общаюсь просто чего-то не знают или правду говорят.
Говорят, что под мобилки и под веб одновременно на реакте писать нельзя.

Comment: Если правильно разнести UI и логику - то вполне можно переиспользовать немалое количество кода. Но так, чтобы "одновременно" - то есть, просто из одного проекта запускать iOS/Android (что возможно) и веб/фронт - это не получится